# Pass a list of string values to a parameterized JUnit test

Tags: java, collections, junit4, parameterized-tests

I am trying to pass a collection of string values from a properties file to a parameterized JUnit test. Properties.values() returns Collection while JUnit requires the parameters be passed in Collection structure.

Does that mean I have to convert `Collection<Object> to Collection<Object[]>`, where each array is actually a single item?

I tried this:

```
Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {{theProperties.values()}});
```

But this puts all the values together in one Object and does not create a Collection as I expect it to. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like parameterized JUnit tests requires a Collection even if each test has a single parameter.

Converting a Collection to Collection:

Using Java 8:

```
Collection<String> c = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
Collection<Object[]> co = c.stream()
                            .map(ele -> new Object[]{ele})
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using Java 7 or below:

```
Collection<String> coll = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
Collection<Object[]> params = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
for (String s : coll) {
    params.add(new Object[] { s });
}
```

For Java 7 or below, you can either:

- write a for loop (as shown above) or
- use Apache Commons [CollectionUtils#collect](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#collect%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Transformer%29) with a Transformer or
- use Guava's [Collections2#transform](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#transform%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) with a function

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can do it in a loop in Java 7? I am getting a little confused there.

Comment: @naspras If my answer addresses your question, please mark it as the correct answer.